# How to change the colors in a piechart (jaspersoft studio)

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I want to change the color of my piecharts to show in a more efficient maner some KPI, is it possible to do so in a chart customizer or directly on jaspersoft studio

Comment: Hello. On stackoverflow it is often good practice to provide an example of what you have tried so far with some example code. Good luck and keep coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the colors in your piechart, you can go in the "Chart Plot" -> "Series Colors" menu:
[image: colors menu]

Comment: Thanks ! It worked, didn't notice taht it was in this menu

Comment: It works, but not quite. If there is more chart sectors than there are colors, some random colors are added. I would expect them to cycle, at least such option should be provided.

Comment: If you want more customization on pie chart colors, it's always possible to create a custom scriptlet